# Binding multiple DropDownListfor with json result from different table MVC entity framework JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api, razor

Here is my json return from API call

```
{"payment":[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Test 12","Value":"35"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Test36","Value":"37"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Test36","Value":"38"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Test36","Value":"39"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"46","Value":"43"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"FirstData","Value":"45"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Livemode","Value":"46"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"TestLive","Value":"47"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"12345","Value":"48"}],"transaction":[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Transactions affect balance always","Value":"1"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Transactions never affect balance","Value":"2"}],"democratic":[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"N = No updates","Value":"1"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"A = All updates","Value":"2"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"E = All updates except email","Value":"3"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"C = All changed updates except email","Value":"4"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"P = Phone updates only","Value":"5"}],"theme":[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Default","Value":"1"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Classic","Value":"2"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Professional","Value":"3"}]}
```

Here the payment,transaction,democratic, themes are list of data  from different table. I want to bind this in razor dropdownlistfor. This is my model name i created how to bind json to this model

```
    public Nullable<int> ProcessorId { get; set; }
    public SelectList TransactionStrategyName { get; set; }
    public SelectList ProcessorName { get; set; }
    public SelectList DemographicReportsName { get; set; }
    public SelectList ThemeName { get; set; }
```

This is my view format for binding dropdown .

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProcessorId,Model.ProcessorName,new { id = "ddlProcessorId", @class = "form-control", @required = true })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProcessorId)
```

This is my service to return the json values

```
 var payment = db.PaymentProcessors.Where(c => c.ClientId == 1).Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.ConfigurationName,
            });
            var transaction = db.TransactionStrategies.Where(c => c.Status == 1).Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.Name,
            });
            var democratic = db.DemographicReports.Where(c => c.Status == 1).Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.Name,
            });
            var theme = db.Themes.Where(c => c.Status == 1).Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.Name,
            });
            return new { payment, transaction,democratic,theme};
```

can anyone help to bind dropdown from this json result

Comment: You need to bind in one dropdownlist all the lists?

Comment: nope in different dropdown;